# How to pass string arraylist into contains() method as parameter?

Tags: java, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");  
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://411mania.com/wrestling/category/tv-report/");
        WebElement contents = driver.findElement(By.className("article_section_wrapper wrestling article_category_wrapper tv-report"));
        List<WebElement> links = contents.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        String clickonlinkTab=Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
        String[] a = {"TALK, WxW, NJPW, Impact","Dark","Elevation"};
        for (int i = links.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!(links.get(i).getText().contains(a))) //Eclipse gives me error at this line.
                    {
                links.get(i).sendKeys(clickonlinkTab);
            }
        }
}
```

I am trying to iterate each links of **TV reports** and skip the links using string arraylist.

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

at hetj.Gssm.main(Gssm.java:26)
```

Comment: the String contains function accept just a CharSequence

Comment: So you want to find out, if a link contains on of the strings "TALK, WxW, NJPW, Impact" or "Dark" or "Elevation"?

Comment: for(word: a){
    if (!(links.get(i).getText().contains(word))){
     links.get(i).sendKeys(clickonlinkTab);
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

The application throws an exception at runtime because the application does not know which value of the 'a' String array to look for.

You would need to iterate trough the 'a' array and check for each value.

It would look like the following:

```
for(WebElement ele: links){
            for(String text:a){

                if (!(ele.getText().contains(text)))
                {
                    ele.sendKeys(clickonlinkTab);
                }

            }
        }
```